# PhpStorm will not compile with ES6 template literals

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, webstorm

**Code:**

```
let name = 'kevin';
console.log(`${name}`);
```

**PhpStorm File Watcher Setup**
[image: File Watcher Setup]

**Issue**
If I use the code above (ES6 template literal), it does not compile (transpile?). Or more accurately it says "*Executing Babel task*" and then the Run Output states "*Process finished with exit code 0*". No errors that I can see.

However, the main file (functions.min.js) does NOT upload. If I change the code to:

```
console.log(name);
```

it works fine....? Been researching for a while now and can't seem to figure out why this is.

I do have a .babelrc file with this inside:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-template-literals"],
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are passing `--presets` to babilon in `Arguments` field - options passed in command line may override the `.babelrc`. Try removing them - does the issue persist?

Comment: Thank you!!!!! That was literally it. I suppose there is no way to mark your comment as the accepted answer?

Comment: I'll add it as the answer:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `--presets` to babilon in File watcher **Arguments** field; but  options passed in command line override the settings in `.babelrc`. Please remove `--presets` from **Arguments**, or make arguments match your `.babelrc` settings by specifying appropriate `--plugins` and `--presets`